# Why is is OK to use a relay to parallel lead-acid battery banks for charging?

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid

I am currently faced with a British-built, Lloyd's offshore certified sailing yacht from 1998. Everything seems to be well-thought out and of the highest build quality. I am thus assuming that their electrical system is equally well designed.

There is one aspect that stumps me: How its 12V lead-acid batteries are charged by the alternator.

Basically, the yacht has two battery banks: one for mainly starting the motor and one for domestic loads. A highly simplified schematic is below.

In normal operation, the battery banks are isolated. When charging from the alternator, however, they are paralleled with a charging relay driven by the alternator regulator "charging" indicator output (D+).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9m0Ou.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In case this is relevant:

- All batteries are [Fullriver DC140-12 (datasheet)](https://fullriverbattery.com/wp-content/uploads/DC140-12.pdf) with 140Ah, 3.6mΩ and ~800 CCA (these are without doubt no longer the originally supplied batteries.)
- The alternator can supply a maximum of 60A.
- The relay is an [Albright SW180-12](https://www.albrightinternational.com/products/sw180/)

My question is this: How does this not result in large instantaneous currents if there is a very large charge balance in the battery banks?

They seem to have explicitly decided that no charge distribution diodes were necessary here, because in other places in the installation they did use charge distribution diodes. I just do not understand how they made this determination.

I would understand if the alternator was a perfect voltage source, but alternators supply limited current (and hence voltage) especially when the motor is idling.

Here is my calculation:

- The starter battery is fully charged at 12.8V at rest.
- The domestic battery bank is fully discharged at 10.4V at rest.
- Let's be generous and assume the alternator is a 60A current source.

If I simulate this, I get a current outflow from the starter battery of 446A.

I do not understand, how this implementation was found to be acceptable, but clearly experienced engineers found this to be a good solution. It has worked flawlessly for 25 years, so I am probably missing something important here.

Comment: What is the output voltage of the alternator?  Probably 13.6V, so current flow is from alternator to batteries.  Less to starter and more to domestic. No alternator, no closing of relay.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat It does not matter what the alternator would like to output. The more discharged battery could still have 11V, less discharged could have 12V, and it would take some time to charge for the voltage to rise to 13.6V. So one battery could easily push a lot of current through the relay to the other battery.

Comment: How long are the wires connecting the relay to the batteries, and what's their AWG / cross-sectional area?

Comment: I agree with you that this doesn't look good.

Comment: Some designs rely on non-ideal characteristics of the parts. For example here, what happens when you try to draw 446A from the starter battery? The voltage will likely sag quickly and current will decrease over several seconds. The battery, wires, and relay *might* be able to survive that. ..But I certainly wouldn't count on it.

Comment: If you take the relay's "30% duty cycle, uninterrupted" load rating (365A), how many milliohms of wiring resistance are needed to reduce the current surge to that value? How does that compare with the wiring actually present? As Drew says, the voltage difference will decrease quite quickly.